# Home Server for Mac based household

Tags: mac, networking, home-server

My home network setup at the moment is very simple, we have an iMac, two MacBooks, a Time Capsule and a wireless Printer.

I'm thinking about changing our setup. Specifically I'd like to have user data stored on, or transferred from the server at logon. Most importantly, I want to have server-side iPhoto libraries, and storage.

Mac OS X Server and Windows Home Server are out of the question, I've been looking more at free options such as Ubuntu server.

What I'd like to know is what would be the best for integration with Mac, and whether the Wi-Fi connection makes any difference to the way it should be set up.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could plug an external USB drive into your Time Capsule and share it with your other Macs over the network.

There's an app in beta called iPhotoSync that lets you sync iPhoto libraries (obviously :-) between Macs.

Mac OS X Server (you can get a Mac Mini server reasonably cheap) is probably much easier to set up for having networked user folders.